# Elasticsearch mapping API popping a 400 error

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

So I am attempting to create a mapping for a new index I created. This is the query I am attempting to put in:

```
PUT /index/_mapping

{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "type": "date"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I put this query into Kibana, it spits out this error.

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "parse_exception",
        "reason" : "request body is required"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "parse_exception",
    "reason" : "request body is required"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

This is confusing because I'm taking the steps from elastic's own mapping page but for some reason keeps popping this error up. I've tried removing the _mapping, removing the "mapping" property but nothing is fixing it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to remove the empty line between the URL and the body

```
PUT /index/_mapping
{                          <--- no empty line here
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "type": "date"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/index/_mapping' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d' {"properties":"@timestamp": { "type": "date"}}}'
```

You use curl option also in Kibana